# C# Add Local object to list<T> then dispose of local object - help understanding?

Tags: c#

I have created an `IDisposable` class object that I store in a `List<T>`. I add objects to the `List<T>` in a function/procedure. However, if I use the `Using{}` notation, the objects in the list get "Disposed" of in the list as well.

```
List<MyObject> MyList = new List<MyObject>;

private void AddObjects() 
{
    using (MyObject Mo = New MyObject())
    {
        Mo.Name = "MyName";
        Mo.Age = 30;
        MyList.Add(Mo);
    }   
}
```

In this instance the objects elements in the list are nulled.  Yet if I use the code:

```
List<MyObject> MyList = new List<MyObject>;

private void AddObjects() 
{
    MyObject Mo = New MyObject()
    Mo.Name = "MyName";
    Mo.Age = 30;
    MyList.Add(Mo);
}
```

Then everything is fine and the object elements in the list are OK.

Question: Why? The MyObject loses scope when the function completes but the reference to the object stays.

Then there's the following code:

```
List<MyObject> MyList = new List<MyObject>;

private void AddObjects() 
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 99; i++)
    {
        MyObject Mo = New MyObject()
        Mo.Name = "MyName";
        Mo.Age = 30 + ctr;
        MyList.Add(Mo);
    }   
}
```

Here the MyObject is being overwritten by a new object but the old one stays - why aren't the previous references being overwritten with the new object?

Comment: `using` automatically calls Dispose() on the object at the end of its scope. If you require access to the objects created outside your using statement, then don't use `using`. The objects in your list are the same ones that you dispose. Use the objects then call Dispose() on them yourself. In the for loop, you are creating new instances of 98 objects and adding them to a List. Why would you imagine that these new objects would overwrite the previous ones? You would have to have declared the object outside the loop and then overwritten it with your new object inside the loop for it to do that.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. What is the expected behavior of your code? What is the actual behavior? You are adding an object to your list and then disposing of it. To me, what you're describing sounds like reasonable behavior, so I'm trying to get a better sense of what your actual question is.

Comment: @DanForbes just because you understand it doesn't mean that the OP does. That is the reason the question is being asked.

Comment: @MattRowland - I don't even understand what the OP was describing as the "actual" behavior. The best I can get is "the objects elements in the list are nulled". Frankly, I'm not exactly sure what that means. I can guess that it means that the value of the object is `null`, but even that isn't exactly what's being said. Without a) the definition of `MyObject.Dispose()` or b) a reproducer that demonstrates exactly what the unexpected behavior is, I'm still lost.

Answer (score 4):

Quick answer:

A `Using` statement that creates a new object will automatically dispose of the object at the end of the using statement.  That is the purpose of `Using`, to dispose of things automatically to prevent the need for manual cleanup. (MSDN link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

**Question 2:**
With the code below, everything is fine and the object elements in the list are OK.

Why? The MyObject loses scope when the function completes but the reference to the object stays.

```
List<MyObject> MyList = new List<MyObject>;

private void AddObjects() 
{
    MyObject Mo = New MyObject()
        Mo.Name = "MyName";
        Mo.Age = 30;
    MyList.Add(Mo);

}
```

**Answer:** 
Your object is now out of scope, but the `MyList` variable still holds a reference to the object that was stored in your `Mo` variable.  The MyList object is still in scope, and it is the same object as before, so the changes are kept.

**Question 3:**
Then there's the following code:

```
List<MyObject> MyList = new List<MyObject>;

private void AddObjects() 
{

    for (int i = 1; i < 99; i++)
    {
        MyObject Mo = New MyObject()
        Mo.Name = "MyName";
        Mo.Age = 30 + ctr;
        MyList.Add(Mo);
    }   
}
```

Here the MyObject is being overwritten by a new object but the old one stays - why aren't the previous references being overwritten with the new object?

**Answer 3:** 
In each loop, you are creating a new variable named `Mo`.  This creates a new address space and a new object each time.

**The main answer**
Don't dispose of things if you want to keep them around.  Dispose of them when you want them gone.